# Android - How to find the name I should use to override existing "?attr" styles?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles, material3, native-android

I two buttons on one of my fragments:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
        android:id="@+id/hide_show_all_models_toggle_group"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/size_small"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/size_medium"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:selectionRequired="true"
        app:singleSelection="true">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/show_all_models_button"
            style="?attr/materialIconButtonOutlinedStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/size_medium"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/size_large"
            android:text="@string/show_all"
            app:icon="@drawable/ic_show"
            app:rippleColor="#6b0000"
            tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/hide_all_models_button"
            style="?attr/materialIconButtonOutlinedStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/size_large"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/size_medium"
            android:text="@string/hide_all"
            app:colorSecondaryContainer="#D2070E"
            app:icon="@drawable/ic_hide"
            app:iconGravity="end"
            app:rippleColor="#6b0000"
            tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry" />

    </com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>
```

However, I would like to style them, like choosing a diferente background, icon color and text color for the button that is selected.

I thought "Well... Let's try and override the `materialIconButtonOutlinedStyle` style!! But them, I had no idea what parent should I use on my style.

I thought it could be `Widget.Material3.Button.OutlinedButton`, so I tried the following:

```
<style name="App.Material3.Button.OutlinedButton" parent="Widget.Material3.Button.OutlinedButton">
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/app_m3_text_button_background_color_selector</item>
</style>
```

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="#D2070E"
        android:state_enabled="true" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:color="?attr/colorContainer"/>
</selector>
```

But that messed with other colors on my button and the button itself. I think that `App.Material3.Button.OutlinedButton` actually translates to `?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle`.

When I hold ctrl + click the ?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle, I got to the `values.xml` file from the Material library, but all I see is this:

```xml
...
    <attr format="reference" name="materialIconButtonFilledStyle"/>
    <attr format="reference" name="materialIconButtonFilledTonalStyle"/>
    <attr format="reference" name="materialIconButtonOutlinedStyle"/>
    <attr format="reference" name="materialIconButtonStyle"/>
...
```

That's not the frist time I intend to overried a theme that I'm using from attr, but I never know wheere I can find it's name to put on the parent atribute of my custom style tag.

Comment: Looks like it's `Widget.Material3.Button.IconButton.Outlined`. I don't have my IDE open atm, but I could've sworn it shows that somewhere. In any case, you can have a look at the source: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/theme/res/values/themes_base.xml#L151.

Comment: Docs on Button Theming:
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Button.md#theming-buttons

Comment: `MaterialButton` should be used instead of a normal `Button`